# mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory after converting lxc to virtual machine

Tags: migration, grub

I've been trying to convert an lxc container to a virtual machine, but I've encountered a problem when trying to boot. I end up with the (initramfs) command line and I've got the following errors:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory

mount: mounting /run on /root/run failed: No such file or directory
run-init: opening console: No such file or directory 

Target filesystem
doesn't have requested /sbin/init.

run-init: opening console: No such
file or directory (repeated a few times)

No init found. Try passing init= bootarg

BusyBox v1.22.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter
'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

From the live cd ubuntu 16.04:

```
blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="3e671c97-7695-49e7-8c83-4527c94d8f14" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="406cef0c-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="c555438a-fd29-4cad-a8cf-fe92c3b78e0b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="406cef0c-02"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-07-31-01-12-13-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="6be2cd0d" PTTYPE="dos



 cat /etc/fstab:

 UUID="3e671c97-7695-49e7-8c83-4527c94d8f14"    /boot   ext4    defaults,noatime0   0 UUID="c555438a-fd29-4cad-a8cf-fe92c3b78e0b"   /   ext4    defaults,noatime0   1
 UUID="688b6a9b-0f30-450c-b8d6-1316c0d17798"    none    swap    defaults    00
```

Relevant parts of /boot/grub/grub.cfg:

```
set root='hd0,msdos2' if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ];
then
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2
 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  c555438a-fd29-4cad-a8cf-fe92c3b78e0belse   search --no-floppy
 --fs-uuid --set=root c555438a-fd29-4cad-a8cf-fe92c3b78e0b fi
```

and:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu
 --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c555438a-fd29-4cad-a8cf-fe92c3b78e0b' {
        recordfail
         load_video
         gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
         insmod gzio
         if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
         insmod part_msdos
         insmod ext2
         set root='hd0,msdos1'
         if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  3e671c97-7695-49e7-8c83-4527c94d8f14
         else
           search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3e671c97-7695-49e7-8c83-4527c94d8f14
         fi
         linux   /vmlinuz-4.15.0-30-generic root=UUID=3e671c97-7695-49e7-8c83-4527c94d8f14 ro  quiet splash
 $vt_handoff initrd  /initrd.img-4.15.0-30-generic }
```

I changed the uuid for the linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-30-generic so that it matches /dev/sda1 and not /dev/sda2. The grub-installer placed the UUID of /dev/sda2, where the root partition is, and I'm not sure why.
Any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Change the UUID back. It was correct originally. Now it is wrong.

Comment: I was able eventually to boot the system. And I was able to do also do it before. The problem is that, after I shut it down or reboot it, it never works the second time. I end up with a blank screen each time after I get past the grub menu. I've no idea what could actually trigger this. Something is really wrong and I'm not sure where I'm supposed to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Should I create another thread with the problem I'm having now, as the question perhaps doesn't seem to be directly related to the current situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realised what the actual problem was after solving the grub issue. The blank screen was related to how the consoles (tty) were identified. Each time the blank screen appeared after the grub menu, the operating system would actually boot fine, but it didn't show anything. But whenever I pressed ctrl+alt F1 or F2, the prompt would show up and everything was actually fine. To solve this issue, I replaced this line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
Works just fine now and the boot process is also displayed on the screen.

Comment: Lethargos, please accept your own answer. You solved your own problem, but you haven't accepted your answer yet. We'll be reminded to get this done until the end of time. Please do this favor to us. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.